# integrity constraint check to make sure employee over age 18

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table to address employee data and would like to add a constraint to my employee table so that people under 18 will not be hired.

```
 CREATE TABLE EMPLOYEE
 (Emp_num    CHAR(4),
  Emp_last   Varchar2(20),
  Emp_First  Varchar2(20), 
  DOB        Date not null,
  Hire_Date  Date Default SYSDATE,
 Constraint  employee_empnum_pk Primary key(Emp_Num),
 Constraint  empee_superid_fk  foreign key(super_ID) reference 
 employee(Emp_Num);
```

I am trying to add a check constraint but not sure how can I define age 18 in this check constraint. What I have tried is `Constraint Employee_age_ck CHECK(DOB+18<= Hire_date)`, but this does not work.

Comment: `add_months` https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions004.htm

Answer (score 0):

Constraint Employee_age_ck CHECK(ADD_MONTHS(DOB,12*18) <= Hire_date)

Answer (score -1):

Try using the DATEDIFF function

```
datediff(year, Hire_date, DOB) < 18
```

Comment: There is no datediff in Oracle.